# How can I dynamic populate an option widget in tkinter depending on a choice from a drop down menu?

Tags: python, tkinter

my problem is the following: I have several files and I have made a drop down menu with the names,the next thing I need is an option menu which can be changed whenever a file name is selected to show some data from the specific file as option.To be clear,my question is only about how to make the option menu change when a choice from the drop down is selected.Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The OptionMenu widget is nothing more than a convenience class that creates a menubutton that is associated with a menu. You can get at this menu via the `"menu"` attribute. The only trick is to knowing what the menu items should do, which is nothing more than setting the value of the associated variable.

Here's an example:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.om_variable = tk.StringVar(self)

        b1 = tk.Button(self, text="Colors", width=8, command=self.use_colors)
        b2 = tk.Button(self, text="Sizes", width=8, command=self.use_sizes)

        self.om = tk.OptionMenu(self, self.om_variable, ())
        self.om.configure(width=20)
        self.use_colors()

        b1.pack(side="left")
        b2.pack(side="left")
        self.om.pack(side="left", fill="x", expand=True)


    def _reset_option_menu(self, options, index=None):
        '''reset the values in the option menu

        if index is given, set the value of the menu to
        the option at the given index
        '''
        menu = self.om["menu"]
        menu.delete(0, "end")
        for string in options:
            menu.add_command(label=string, 
                             command=lambda value=string:
                                  self.om_variable.set(value))
        if index is not None:
            self.om_variable.set(options[index])

    def use_colors(self):
        '''Switch the option menu to display colors'''
        self._reset_option_menu(["red","orange","green","blue"], 0)

    def use_sizes(self):
        '''Switch the option menu to display sizes'''
        self._reset_option_menu(["x-small", "small", "medium", "large"], 0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: So, are you saying in order to dynamically add menu items to an already instantiated menu that you have to delete the menu items before you can make new ones?

Comment: @user2962794: no, that's not quite what I'm saying. There's no requirement to delete the items that are there. At its heart it's just a menu, and you have full access to all menu methods. You can insert new items, and delete or modify existing items.

Comment: Sorry. I figured it out. I had some bug or something in my code that prevented the dynamic menu items from appearing (and so I found this question, and asked for clarification). It works as I had originally hoped (you don't have to add the menu items in the menu creation, I mean). However, it's good to hear the clarification! :)

Answer (score -1):

As the OptionMenu gives a command option, i would suggest to keep reference to the command already given (if any) and pass it to the new options this way:

attendion, variables based on the previous answer

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
    self.command=kwargs['command']
    ...

def _reset_option_menu(options, index=None):
    ...
    menu.add_command(label=string, 
                     command=lambda:self.command(),
                     value=self.om_variable.set(string))                         
        ...
```

Hope its of any use
Btw, really usefull the answer given by Bryan Oakley,