# Can I register a callback for change event in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

The code,

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()
Label(master, text="Current Age: ").grid(row=0, column=0)
current = StringVar(master)
current.set("0")

coption = OptionMenu(master, current, *[str(i) for i in range(95)])
coption.grid(row=0,column=1)

Label(master, text="Target Age: ").grid(row=1, column=0)

target = StringVar(master)
target.set("0") # default deger

toption = OptionMenu(master, target, *[str(i) for i in range(95)])
toption.grid(row=1,column=1)

mainloop()
```

I have 2 comboboxes, one for current age, and one for target age. I want target age to contain only values that are above current age. Therefore, I think I need to register on change callback somehow. I searched the google, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have the function that modifies the target menuoptions and the event that triggers it:

```
def changed(*args):
    start = current.get()
    print(start)
    menu = toption["menu"]
    menu.delete(0, END)
    for age in range(int(start), 95):
        menu.add_command(label=age,
                         command=lambda v=target, l=age: v.set(l))                
    target.set(start)

current.trace('w', changed)
```

This has taken in part from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393430/how-can-i-dynamic-populate-an-option-widget-in-tkinter-depending-on-a-choice-fro), [here](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2005-July/040018.html) and [here](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tkinter-discuss/2006-October/000928.html).

Comment: Thanks. But after setting current age, target age gets fixed that I can't change it's value any more.

Answer (score 1):

It should be clear that `OptionMenu` is a poor choice for the situation, no one likes to select an option over a menu of 95 entries. Anyway, you don't need to depend on Tcl variable tracing to do the update, just remember about the `command` argument that `OptionMenu` accepts. Using that, your problem is solved as in:

```
import Tkinter

AGELIMIT = 95
AGEOPT = [str(i) for i in range(AGELIMIT)]

def update_agelist(currage):
    # Rewrite the Menubutton associated with the Optionmenu.
    menu = toption['menu']
    menu.delete(0, 'end')
    for age in range(int(currage), AGELIMIT):
        menu.add_command(label=age, command=Tkinter._setit(target, age))

    target.set(currage)


master = Tkinter.Tk()
Tkinter.Label(text=u"Current Age: ").grid(row=0, column=0)

current = Tkinter.StringVar(value='0')
coption = Tkinter.OptionMenu(master, current, *AGEOPT, command=update_agelist)
coption.grid(row=0,column=1)

Tkinter.Label(text=u"Target Age: ").grid(row=1, column=0)

target = Tkinter.StringVar(value='0')
toption = Tkinter.OptionMenu(master, target, *AGEOPT)
toption.grid(row=1, column=1)

master.mainloop()
```