# Updating Dropboxes in Tkinter Dynamicaly

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a tkinter program which takes in the policy number and date of birth of a customer. I wanted to create dropbox menus each for day, month, and year for obtaining the date of birth. So here's what I did:

```
years=[1975,1976,1977,1978,1979,1980,1981,1982,1983,1984,1985,1986,1987,1988,1989,1990,1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000]
months=['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December']
days=[01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30]

clicked1=IntVar()
clicked2=StringVar()
clicked3=IntVar()

dof_year=OptionMenu(root,clicked1,*years)
dof_month=OptionMenu(root,clicked2,*months)
dof_day=OptionMenu(root,clicked3,*days)
```

But then I realized a serious problem. Months have 30 and 31 days alternatively and February has 28 or 29 days.

I could prompt the user to first enter the year and month and click a button, then by using if-else statements, determine how many days I am supposed to give in the dropbox menu, and then show the days menu.

But that will look really unprofessional. So is there a way that when the user inputs the year and month, the "days" list updates dynamically without pressing any button?

Like for example, when I choose the year 1980 and the month "March", the 'days' menu instantly updates itself, so that when i click it, it shows me the exact number of days in that month.

Thanks!

Comment: what about tkcalendar?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443786/how-do-i-create-a-date-picker-in-tkinter

Comment: @MVB76 That would be nice too. But what about this method?

Comment: See [how-can-i-dynamic-populate-an-option-widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393430/how-can-i-dynamic-populate-an-option-widget-in-tkinter-depending-on-a-choice-fro/7403530#7403530)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check here: [Changing the options of a OptionMenu when clicking a Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580218/changing-the-options-of-a-optionmenu-when-clicking-a-button)
on how to update the list of options in an `OptionMenu`. It is pretty cumbersome as `OptionMenu` has limited setters for updating its properties.

First choice would be to use a dedicated calendar widget.

Overwise, it would be much easier if you use a `ComboBox` which is quite similar visually and can be easily updated.
Here is some sample code:

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
years=[1975,1976,1977,1978,1979,1980,1981,1982,1983,1984,1985,1986,1987,1988,1989,1990,1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000]
months=['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December']

def on_month():
    if month.get() in ('January','to be completed'):
        days = list(range(1,30))
    else:
        days = list(range(1,31))
    # todo: handle 28/29 days for Feb depending on year
    m.config(values=days)


year=tk.IntVar()
month=tk.StringVar()
day=tk.IntVar()

y = ttk.Combobox(root,values=years,state="readonly")
y.pack()

m = ttk.Combobox(root,values=months,state="readonly")
m.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", on_month)
m.pack()

d = ttk.Combobox(root,values=list(range(1,31)),state="readonly")
d.pack()
root.mainloop()
```